# Finding the midway between two points

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a bunch of HTML elements that I want to connect with lines via Canvas. Here's a mockup of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Mockup]

Currently, I just have the lines, with no text. I want to place text halfway between each line, but seeing as they're diagonals I'm not sure how to do it.

Current code:

```
// 'connectors' is an array of points corresponding to 
// the middle of each big blue buttons' x-value 

ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
for(var i=0;i<connectors.length;i++){
    var wpoint = connectors[i];
    var pos1   = {w: wpoint, h: 0};
    var pos2   = {w: canvas.width / 2, h: canvas.height};
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(pos1.w,pos1.h);
    ctx.lineTo(pos2.w,pos2.h);
    ctx.stroke();

    // Write Text Halfway 
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.font = "bold 16px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("2702", 100, canvas.height / 2); 
    // No idea what to put as the x value here

}
```

What's the best way to achieve this? Potentially drawing half the line, writing the text, then drawing the rest of the line?

**EDIT**: Perhaps a better title / question would be: How do I find the midpoint between two arbitrary points in HTML Canvas? I want to draw text there.

Comment: just wondering since the lines are angled won't the text not all appear at the same level because the middle of the slanted line is going to be different height than the middle of the most strait line

Comment: @johnny5 good point - I think the solution is to find the correct `x-value`, and plot the `y-value` to half of the canvas' height.

Comment: it might be easier to draw the lines, find a point on each one on the same y axis, then erase part of the like and draw your text in over it

Comment: yeah pretty much the same as what you just said

Comment: @johnny5 Yep. I've updated the question / sample code to reflect this. But still, no idea how to find that X value :)

Comment: is the end point always going to be the same or could it change?

Comment: What I mean is are the lines always going to be proportional or could they change?

Comment: @johnny5 the end-point of each line will always be `canvas.witdth / 2, canvas.height`.

Comment: will the canvas height always be the same or could that change?

Comment: @johnny5 at present it's static, although in case I make it responsive I'd like to just calculate the height with `canvas.height`.

Comment: the proper way would probably be, caculate the slope of the angle from the two end points. then take the middle height from the strait line in the middle, then use Pythagorean theorem, to caculate the middle point of the line based off of the x distance to the point, the angle and the expected height

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

**Here's how:**

- Calculate the line's midpoint
- Draw the line
- Erase the line at its midpoint
- Tell canvas to horizontally & vertically center any drawn text around a specified [x,y]
- Draw the text at the midpoint

**Here's annotated code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var line={x0:20,y0:20,x1:150,y1:150};

textAtMidLine(line,'2702','verdana',14)

function textAtMidLine(line,text,fontface,fontsize){

  // save the unmodified context state
  ctx.save();

  // calc line's midpoint
  var midX=line.x0+(line.x1-line.x0)*0.50;
  var midY=line.y0+(line.y1-line.y0)*0.50;

  // calc width of text
  ctx.font=fontsize+'px '+fontface;
  var textwidth=ctx.measureText(text).width;

  // draw the line
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(line.x0,line.y0);
  ctx.lineTo(line.x1,line.y1);
  ctx.lineWidth=2;
  ctx.strokeStyle='lightgray';
  ctx.stroke();

  // clear the line at the midpoint
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-out'; // "erases" 
  ctx.fillRect(midX-textwidth/2,midY-fontsize/2,textwidth,fontsize*1.286);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';  // reset to default

  // tell canvas to horizontally & vertically center text around an [x,y]
  ctx.textAlign='center';
  ctx.textBaseline='middle'

  // draw text at the midpoint
  ctx.fillText(text,midX,midY);

  // restore the unmodified context state
  ctx.restore();

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: does this find the middle point of the line or does? I think the op wants it to caculate the middle point of the middle line translated across all lines

Comment: @johnny5 It finds the midpoint of each specified line. If all lines have the same `y0` & `y1` (as in the question's example image) then the code will work unmodified. And yes, if you want to assign a middle `y` then you can clamp all drawing to that middle y. If you want that middle y to be at the midpoint of a vertical area then you can use the same  `midX` & `midY` calculation against that vertical area (using x0=0 & x1=0 to make the defining line vertical ).

Comment: Works for me! You'd think something so seemingly simple would have an easy method in Javascript, sadly not.

Comment: If you normalise the vector from `P1` to `P2` to get `nx`, `ny` and the line `length` then the text would require a gap  equal to `gap = Math.sqrt(textWidth * textWidth + textHeight * textHeight)` which is the hypotenuse of the triangle over the text you then draw two lines from `P1.x`, `P1.y` to `P1.x+nx*(length/2- gap/2)` and `P1.y + ny * (length / 2 - gap / 2)` then from `P1.x + nx * (length / 2 + gap / 2)` and `P1.y + ny * (length / 2 + gap / 2)` to `P2.x`, `P2.y`  you avoid having to clear the area for the text, which would be problematic if you have a detailed background

Comment: @Blindman67. Sure, why not -- lots of solutions really. You could also stage your `line + erase + fillText` on a separate canvas and then `drawImage` the staging canvas to the main canvas.